# MASM bubble sort in descending order

Tags: assembly, masm, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort a list in descending order, using a bubble sort but I'm having two problems.  The first is that the following code is inserting a 0 as the first element for a reason I don't understand (I thought maybe it was the array's fault, but it doesn't exist when this sort isn't used, so I don't know where its coming from.  The second problem is that this implementation sorts in ascending order, and I cannot figure out how to fix it to do the oppossite.  If I can figure out the zero thing a simple swap could be done, I suppose.  I have the dual problem of not being great with MASM and not being good at implementing sorts in a language I don't understand very well.

Code:

call from main:

```
push count ; size of the array
push OFFSET list ; the array
call sortList
```

procedure:

```
sortList Proc
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
mov ecx,[ebp+12]
mov edx,[ebp+8]
bs_o:
xor ebp,ebp
bs_i:
mov eax,DWORD PTR [edx+ebp*4+4]
cmp DWORD PTR [edx+ebp*4],eax
jb @F
xchg eax,DWORD PTR [edx+ebp*4]
mov DWORD PTR [edx+ebp*4+4],eax
@@:
add ebp,1
cmp ebp,ecx
jb bs_i
loop bs_o
pop ebp
retn 8
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It appears to be omitting the highest value

Comment: I figured out the value problem, count was set 1 value too high, so it was taking the memory location after the array (set to 0 in most cases) as part of the sort.  Still could use help in getting it to sort in decreasing order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The second problem is that this implementation sorts in ascending order, and I cannot figure out how to fix it to do the oppossite.

Invert the branching condition after comparing the two elements. That is, instead of `jb $F`, do `jae @F`.